# Is $\cos \cos 1 - \sin \sin \sin 1$ positive?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

How can I show that

$$\cos \cos 1 - \sin \sin \sin 1$$

is positive?

This is motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/131352/5531).  If

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \cos \cos \cos \cos(\pi/2 + ix) - \sin \sin \sin \sin(\pi/2+ix)\\
     &= \cos \cos \cos \sinh x - \sin \sin \sin \cosh x,
\end{align}$$

then it looks like $f(x)$ has a zero in the interval $(0,1)$.  This would imply that

$$
\cos \cos \cos \cos(z) - \sin \sin \sin \sin(z)
$$

has infinitely-many zeros in the strip $0 < \Im(z) < 1$.

One way to show that such a zero exists would be to show that $f(1) < 0 < f(0)$, the right-side of which is the current question.  I don't know how to show the left side either, but now I'm interested in this question for its own sake.

Comment: If there is a more appropriate tag please feel free to suggest :)

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the values with a computer calculator? If yes, then verifying the computation shouldn't be such a difficult task.

Comment: Look it up in a table. If just this one value is at stake and it is not $0.000000013$ then anyone could do an estimate with pencil and paper if (s)he is not convinced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that
$$
1-\frac{1}{2}x^2 \;<\; \cos x \;<\; 1-\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{24}x^4
$$
for $x>0$.  From the upper bound, we see that $\cos 1 < 13/24$.  Since $\cos$ is decreasing, it follows that
$$
\cos(\cos 1) \;>\; \cos\left(\frac{13}{24}\right) \;>\; 1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{13}{24}\right)^2 \;>\; 0.85.
$$
Next, recall that
$$
\sin x < x
$$
for all $x>0$.  Since $\sin x$ is increasing, this gives us
$$
\sin\sin\sin 1 \;<\; \sin \sin 1 \;<\; \sin 1.
$$
But we also know that
$$
\sin x \;<\; x - \frac{1}{6}x^3 + \frac{1}{120}x^5
$$
for all $x>0$.  It follows that
$$
\sin\sin\sin 1 \;<\; \sin 1 \;<\; \frac{101}{120} \;<\; 0.85.
$$

Comment: Of course, this kind of estimation proof isn't really necessary.  If you want to know whether $\cos\cos 1$ or $\sin\sin\sin 1$ is bigger, you can just plug them into a calculator and get an answer.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to do this without a calculator.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have written your question as you want it, since 
$$ \cos\cos\cos 1= 0.65< \sin \sin \sin 1=0.67$$

If you really want only two $\cos$ iterations in the left then the inequality is true and you can prove it like this:

$$\cos(\cos(1))=\sin(\pi/2-\cos 1)>\sin 1$$

since $f(x)=\cos x+x$ is strictly increasing and $f(\pi/2)=\pi/2$. Therefore $f(1)<\pi/2$ and using the monotonicity of $\sin $ on $[0,\pi/2]$ you are done.

It remains to notice that $$ \sin 1 >\sin \sin 1>\sin \sin \sin 1$$